# How can I redirect a page if it is taking too long to load

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, pageload

I am attempting to build a web page which will be viewed on a wide variety of pages.  I am noticing that, although it loads quickly on my PC, it takes an uncomfortable tong time to load of other smaller devices.  I would like to make a one-size-fits-all solution which will redirect the page to another url if the page load is taking too long.  Here is my initial plan

- add a script (to all of my pages) that sends an ajax call to the server once the page is done loading.
- if the call is received within a second of the original request, do nothing.
- otherwise, save a flag of some kind (to a session or the database) which triggers the redirect.

I am not sure how to put together the next part.  I know that PHP can redirect via headers, but after one second, I'm assuming that the headers have already been sent.  Is this even possible?  I think that I have seen this behavior on other pages.

Comment: You can check if an element exists in the page after x seconds , if not redirect

Comment: Find out what is causing the delay, then either optimize it to avoid delay in the first place(best outcome), or load that part via ajax, with a timeout.

Comment: You could probably try using a meta refresh method with a 10-30 second value. Other than that, I never ran into that situtation myself and never had to Google it to find out how, if there are better methods than a meta refresh method; which probably do exist.

Comment: [**This answer on SO**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4481081/) could be of help.

Comment: @user574632 -ii- I like the ajax method (but it would require some major, site-wide changes.)  Could you say more about that?

Comment: @Fred -ii- What is the meta refresh method?  is it a PHP or Javascript method?  Will it function before a page is completely loaded?

Comment: This `<META http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL=http://www.example.com">` @Hoytman `10` being the amount of seconds.

Comment: I am familiar with this tag, but does the ten second countdown start the moment the headers reach the page or from the moment that the page is rendered?  Also, is there a way to cancel it with JavaScript?